# Haskell - typeclass extension

Tags: haskell

I've got a question about type classes. I've got the following code:

```
import Foreign.C.Types (CDouble, CFloat)

class Floating a => Trigonometry a where

    versin :: a -> a
    versin x = 1 - cos x

    vercos :: a -> a
    vercos x = 1 + cos x

    coversin :: a -> a
    coversin x = 1 - sin x

    covercos :: a -> a
    covercos x = 1 + sin x

    haversin :: a -> a
    haversin x = versin x * 0.5

    havercos :: a -> a
    havercos x = vercos x * 0.5

    hacoversin :: a -> a
    hacoversin x = coversin x * 0.5

    hacovercos :: a -> a
    hacovercos x = covercos x * 0.5

instance Trigonometry CDouble
instance Trigonometry CFloat
instance Trigonometry Double
instance Trigonometry Float
```

Now my question is: there can be infinite amount of `Floating` instances, and obviously every single instance of `Floating` can be an instance of `Trigonometry` without extra implementation. Is there a way to avoid the explicit instance declarations at the bottom and automatically make all `Floating` instances become `Trigonometry` instance too?

Cheers!

Comment: Just implement the functions *without* a typeclass: `versin :: Floating a => a -> a` as top level functions. There is no need to implement these in a typeclass: these can be used for all `Floating` instances.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, yes that's true, very good point. The only difference is having the typeclass allows specific implementations for specific instances.

Answer (score 6):

For this case, there is probably no need to define a typeclass at all, you can implement these functions as top level functions with a `Floating` type constraint:

```
versin :: Floating a => a -> a
versin x = 1 - cos x

vercos :: Floating a => a -> a
vercos x = 1 + cos x

coversin :: Floating a => a -> a
coversin x = 1 - sin x

covercos :: Floating a => a -> a
covercos x = 1 + sin x

haversin :: Floating a => a -> a
haversin x = versin x * 0.5

havercos :: Floating a => a -> a
havercos x = vercos x * 0.5

hacoversin :: Floating a => a -> a
hacoversin x = coversin x * 0.5

hacovercos :: Floating a => a -> a
hacovercos x = covercos x * 0.5
```

If you want to make a special implementation for a certain `Floating` type, you can indeed work with a typeclass, but if you implement an `instance Floating a => Trigonometry a`, you likely will end up with [overlapping instances](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-declarations-and-resolution).

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for something similar, I figured it out:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Algorithms.Math.Trigonometry where

class Floating a => Trigonometry a where

    versin :: a -> a
    versin x = 1 - cos x

    vercos :: a -> a
    vercos x = 1 + cos x

    coversin :: a -> a
    coversin x = 1 - sin x

    covercos :: a -> a
    covercos x = 1 + sin x

    haversin :: a -> a
    haversin x = versin x * 0.5

    havercos :: a -> a
    havercos x = vercos x * 0.5

    hacoversin :: a -> a
    hacoversin x = coversin x * 0.5

    hacovercos :: a -> a
    hacovercos x = covercos x * 0.5

instance Floating a => Trigonometry a
```

Language extension magic :)

Comment: This means you can't have other instances for other types. This instance you declared applies to _all_ types, not just ones with a `Floating` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want Haskell to infer that other types are instances of `Trigonometry` - that would lead to situations where it was using capabilities on types because it found a typeclass lying around that seemed to apply.  For example, you might deliberately omit an `Ord` instance on a type for which it could easily be inferred because `Ord` doesn't make sense for that type.

If you want a function to apply to any suitable type, you simply remove the typeclass.